# EM algorithm for a mixture of three normal distributions throws errors

Tags: r, normal-distribution, expectation-maximization

I need to run an EM algorithm for a mixture of three normal distributions with unknows means and variances. My data points are a column with 500 rows. I am gonna take it as 'S'.

First I need to write a function for negative log-likelihood of the mixture model.
Here is what I wrote:

```
S <- df$Height

neg.logl = function(theta, p1, p2,x){
  mu1 = theta[1]
  mu2 = theta[2]
  mu3 = theta[3]
  sigma1 = exp(theta[4]) 
  sigma2 = exp(theta[5]) 
  sigma3 = exp(theta[6])
  f.x = p1 * dnorm(x, mu1, sigma1) + 
    p2*dnorm(x, mu2, sigma2) +
    (1-p1-p2)*dnorm(x, mu3, sigma3)
  sum(-log(f.x))
}
```

Then I need to run the EM algorithm for 10 iterations for three different starting points. I am gonna take one starting point at one time and run the algorithm for three times seperately.

```
set.seed(30000)
max.iter = 10; n=nrow(df)
p1.comp1 = matrix(NA, max.iter, n)
p2.comp1 = matrix(NA, max.iter, n)
theta_EM = matrix(NA, max.iter, 6)
p1.comp1[1, ] = runif(n,0.1,0.3)
p2.comp1[1, ] = runif(n,0.2,0.3)

# Running first M step
theta_EM[1, ] = optim(c(-0.5, 0.5, -0.2, 0.2), function(theta)
  neg.logl(theta, p1.comp1[1,],p2.comp1[1, ], S))$par

# Running alternate E and M steps
for(i in 2:max.iter){
# E step: update probability memberships
p1.temp = cbind(dnorm(S, theta_EM[i-1, 1], exp(theta_EM[i-1, 4])),
  dnorm(S, theta_EM[i-1, 2], exp(theta_EM[i-1, 5])),
  dnorm(S, theta_EM[i-1, 3], exp(theta_EM[i-1, 6])))
p2.temp = cbind(dnorm(S, theta_EM[i-1, 1], exp(theta_EM[i-1, 4])),
  dnorm(S, theta_EM[i-1, 2], exp(theta_EM[i-1, 5])),
  dnorm(S, theta_EM[i-1, 3], exp(theta_EM[i-1, 6])))
p1.comp1[i, ] = p1.temp[ , 1] / rowSums(p1.temp)
p2.comp1[i, ] = p2.temp[ , 1] / rowSums(p2.temp)

# M step: update parameter estimates
theta_EM[i, ] = optim(theta_EM[i-1, ],
function(theta) neg.logl(theta, p1.comp1[i,],p2.comp1[i, ], S))$par
}

#Final
theta.last = theta_EM[max.iter, ]
p1.temp = cbind(dnorm(S, theta.last[1], exp(theta.last[4])),
  dnorm(x, theta.last[2], exp(theta.last[5])))
p2.temp = cbind(dnorm(S, theta.last[2], exp(theta.last[5])),
  dnorm(x, theta.last[2], exp(theta.last[6])))
p3.temp = cbind(dnorm(S, theta.last[3], exp(theta.last[6])),
  dnorm(x, theta.last[2], exp(theta.last[6])))
p1.last = p1.temp[ , 1]/rowSums(p1.temp)
p2.last = p2.temp[ , 1]/rowSums(p2.temp)
p2.last = p3.temp[ , 1]/rowSums(p3.temp)
logl.last = - neg.logl(theta.last, p1.last, p2.last,S)
cat("EP:",
c(theta.last[1], theta.last[2], theta.last[3],exp(theta.last[4]), 
    exp(theta.last[5],exp(theta.last[6])),
    "\nlogl:", logl.last)
```

Then I get so many errors! Please help

Answer (score 0):

The errors thrown connected with improper matrix initialization and then the `theta_EM` assignment. It is recommended to use `mixtools` package for EM algorithm implementation. Please see below code where at first sample with 500 elements generated then one-liner `normalmixEM` invoked.

```
library(mixtools)

# Sample generated
# Vector with 500 elements generated
# Mixture of 3 normal distributions
n <- 500
lambda <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)
mu <- c(0, 5, 10)
sigma <- c(1, 10, 30)
mixnorm_data <- rnormmix(n, lambda, mu, sigma)

## EM algorithm application

out <- normalmixEM(mixnorm_data, k = 3, arbvar = TRUE, epsilon = 1e-03)

## Results are consistent with mixture distribution parameters
out$lambda
# [1] 0.1652959 0.5699273 0.2647769
out$mu
# 5.65048569 -0.07448014  7.85020009
out$sigma
# 9.658122  1.043050 24.831176
```